# Windows 7 doesn't generate wake event in system log

Tags: windows-7, sleep, event-log, wake-up

I set up a scheduled task to run with this event as a trigger:

```
Log: System
Source:Power-Troubleshooter
Event ID: 1
```

But I don't see any event in the system log. 
The only event which time is nearest to wake is:
    Log: System
    Source: Kernel-General
    Event ID: 1

But this event occurs many times a day after system start so it's not sutable.

Is there any way to allow Windows generate wake event in system log?

Comment: Hmm. No repro here in Windows 7. I get the appropriate event in my system log.

Comment: @harrymc You've marked the issue as a duplicate. Would you be so kind to point me the solution exactly?